# Is a superset also open if the subset is a open set

Tags: general-topology

In Munkres Topology book, section on basis in example 4 it is given that there exists a basis element B such that

x $\in$ B and B $\subset$ U so that **U is open by definition**

I do not understand how is U open because the definition of open set is **A subset U of a X is an open set of X if U belongs to the topology collection T**

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is likely that $x$ is an arbitrary element of $U$. That's why $U$ is open.

Answer (score 2):

You are misunderstanding the sentence. Its by the definition of the basis of the topology, not by the definition of the openness of the set!

One of the equivalent definitions of the topology basis is:

*A collection of open sets $\mathcal{B}$ is a basis if for any point $x$ in an open set $U$ there exists $B\in \mathcal{B}$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$.*

Hence, the reformulation of the cited statement would be:

**Let $x\in X$. Then there exists an open set $U$ such that $x\in U$ and, by the definition of the topology basis, a basis element $B$ such that $x\in B\subseteq U$.**

Comment: Ohh thank you now everything makes sense